# How to get all input fields with particular attribute?

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" someCustomAttr="value"></input>
```

This code sometimes work sometimes not:

```
$fields = $('input[someCustomAttr="value"]','#contaners_id');
```

Is this ok?

Comment: Suggestion: Use `data-*` attributes. Your code looks fine

Comment: looks perfect... it will work if the `someCustomAttr` has the value `value`, if the attribute value is something else then it work work like `<input type="text" someCustomAttr="newvalue"></input>`

Comment: You need to make sure you have a container around the input with ID "contaners_id" in order for it to work with that selector syntax

Comment: Ok thanks. Now to see where is an error :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Change `someCustomAttr="value"` to `data-custom="value"`.
2. Use `$('input[data-custom="value"]);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the attribute and don't care about the value, then do:

```
$fields = $('input[data-custom]');
```

Additionally, if you want elements besides inputs that also have that attribute, then just do:

```
$fields = $('[data-custom]');
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work :

```
<input type="text" someCustomAttr="value" value="fdfgfdg"></input>


<div></div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/UYTKr/)**

If it isn't worked yet, Change Jquery lib version and Use one such as used by jsfiddle in this demo : 
http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/UYTKr/